# minimize the heights geeksforgeeks java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, data-structures

i'm trying to solve the dsa problem on gfg where i couldn't able to understand the problem statment.
[problem link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimize-the-heights3351/1#)

one thing i know that in this problem is, i need to find the min value and i need to find the min height. in this case i used this code for

```
class Solution {
    public int smallestRangeII(int[] A, int K) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        int n = A.length;
        int res = A[n - 1] - A[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int max = Math.max(A[i] + K, A[n - 1] - K);
            int min = Math.min(A[i + 1] - K, A[0] + K);
            res = Math.min(res, max - min);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

the code link which i used to understand this [code link](https://leetcode.com/problems/smallest-range-ii/discuss/173505/Java-Solution-with-the-Picture-to-explain-it)

In this code i couldn't able to understand why we need to find the min.

i want to know why we are updating min if we can use arr[0] for minimun element.